# Is it possible to replace a string (zipped) code from apk dalvik

Tags: android, python, apk

I would like to replace a single string from the hex/dalvik apk code.  I realize this would entail finding how the string gets encoded when it is converted from an Android class project into a signed apk file.

Is this possible?  Well, I know in code, anythings possible.. but does anyone here know how to do it?  I have learned that it's possible to delete and add to .apk files on a windows platform with a simple zip archive (such as replacing icons for the SystemUI.apk), without breaking the apk.. but how would one do it programmatically?  Specifically in python?

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

I have tried:

```
import zipfile
zf=zipfile.ZipFile('APK.apk') # my zip file
for filename in ['classes.dex']: # zipped file content file
 data=zf.read(filename)
data=data.replace('mystring','newstring') #replace string within the content file
file=open('classes.dex','wb')
file.write(data) # write NEW content file to local disk
file.close()
zin=zipfile.ZipFile('APK.apk','r')       # create zip in and zip out
zout=zipfile.ZipFile('APK.apk','w')      # iterate through zipped contents and
for item in zin.infolist():              # copy all EXCEPT 'classes.dex' content file
  buffer=zin.read(item.filename)
  if (item.filename!='classes.dex'):
    zout.writestr(item,buffer)
zout.close()
zin.close()
zf=zipfile.ZipFile('APK.apk',mode='a')   # finally, add new content file from my local disk
zf.write('classes.dex',arcname='classes.dex')
zf.close()
```

This takes the original APK.apk file, and rewrites a string within one of the zipped content files, then repacking it back to APK.apk.   Problem is:
ORIGINAL APK.apk   =   170 kb
NEW  APK.apk       =   399 kb   and NOT INSTALLABLE, the apk was "broken", and the Android system won't install the apk.

Comment: I don't know anything about apk's, but if you say that it is essentially a zip file, than you should look into the [zipfile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile) module.

Comment: I have tried, zipfile is useful, and it seems to unzip the apk file and contents just fine, but it's the re-zipping that's the problem.  I've tried every possible compression type I can find, but strangely zipfile "knows" which compression to UNcompress with, but I can't seem to REcompress in the same way, as the file sizes of the zipped content file changes drastically when comparing the original to the recompressed.

Comment: please see Question edit..

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a string with higher bytes than the original.. you have to replace a string of particular size with the same size of string. Try lucky patcher. It replaces string in your Android only.. no need to bring it to your pc. :-)